# Alternative for PDF viewer in ASP.net website

Tags: asp.net

I have several result grids in my asp.net website. I want to view/print them in separate pages  on click of a button. Currently i am converting them to PDF, Is there any other way to view/print them because, for pdf we need pdf viewer tool to be installed.

Comment: Webpages can be viewed and printed already, can't they?  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: Look up some info on creating a stylesheet for print.  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types

Comment: Question is unclear. Before you convert to PDF you already have the data. You can convert into whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already printing them to PDF you can user Mozilla PDF.JS to view the PDF files without the need of a browser plugin http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/.